# Changing the height of ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

I have an imageView below my first textView and a textView below that image. So I want to re-size the imageView to have a smaller height so that it would not take up more than half the screen. But so far when I try to change the height to either wrap_content or match_parent however it is just still the same size. I also tried setting a max height but does not seem to be doing anything.

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gblue" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faq_story1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/faqpt1"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/faq_pic1"
        android:src="@drawable/skull"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:maxHeight="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/faq_story2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/faq_story1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faq_story2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/faqpt2"/>"

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: have edit my ans now checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this hope it is worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_gblue" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/faq_story1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/faqpt1"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/faq_pic1"
    android:src="@drawable/skull"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:maxHeight="10dp"

    android:layout_below="@+id/faq_story1"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/faq_story2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/faq_pic1"

    android:text="@string/faqpt2"/>"

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It didn't seem to work for me the image been displayed is still the same size on the screen.

Comment: Thank it seems to be working for the height but the image's width is not stretching across anymore. The image now appears to be a small little box in the center of the screen.

Comment: yes,but u can set the image height as u want,if this ans worked for you then mark as a correct,that others will find a sloution easily.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faq_story1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/faqpt1"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faq_story2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/faqpt2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/faq_pic1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/faq_story2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/skull"
        android:layout_below="@+id/faq_story1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```